# GeoServer - layer is read only (it already has a primary key)

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, tomcat

I created a simple table in my Postgres\PostGIS DB. I then created the GeoServer layer with the SQL:

```
select * from tablename
```

I'm trying a WFS Transaction, like I usually do (and it works on similar tables!) to add data to that layer. I get this error:

```
{http://myorganization.org}layername is read-only
```

It's a common error, that's usually due to the lack of a primary key in the "tablename" table. But the table has a primary key!

```
create table tablename(
serialID serial PRIMARY KEY,
field1 text,
field2 text,
field3 text,
field4 timestamp without time zone,
geom geometry
);
```

I already have other tables where the Transaction works in the same GeoServer instance, so it's not a system wide option or lack of permission to the tomcat user. How do I fix this error?

Comment: can you explain why you used a view which doesn't modify the table, just publishing a layer based on the table is easier

Comment: That was my mistake. I have always only used SQL Views and thought that was the way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your mistake? @iant I'm having the same problem and I'm not sure what's the solution

Answer (score 2):

Layers published as sql views are not editable, you have to publish them as normal tables instead

Comment: Also documented in http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html: `SQL Views are read-only, and thus cannot be updated by WFS-T transactions`

Comment: Andre could you please clarify that? I might have this problem and I'm not sure how to go from SQL view to normal table